# Fourier transform of heaviside step function

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft, sympy

I want to compute the Fourier transform of these functions:
1)

```
t * exp(at) * sin(at) * u(-t)
```

2. 

```
a * rect(t/4a) * [\delta(t+2a) + 2\delta(t) + \delta(t-2a)]
```

I wrote this block of code but I got a bizarre result.

```
from sympy import sin, exp, pi, Heaviside, fourier_transform
from sympy.abc import a, t, k
fourier_transform(t* exp(a*t)* sin(a*t)*Heaviside(-t), t, k)
```

How can I express the Heaviside step function in sympy? What is \theta in sympy (it appears in the result)?

Comment: The Heaviside functions is displayed as theta.

Comment: @thank you so much!